# is it possible to use crop classification, health assessment of crops and crop yielding prediction in the same model

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks, recurrent-neural-networks, support-vector-machine

I was wondering if it is possible to create a model in which the crop data is used for classification of crops and thenthe outputs is subsequently used for health assessment of that particular crop and after the health assessment to predict the yield . and i yes which appproach should i use?

Comment: Can you provide more details about what you mean by "crop data" provide some actual examples with real images that we can see? What are some possible labels in your case? This post is not very clear (at least to me).